# Install apps(games) on only one user

Tags: windows, windows-10

I have a gaming PC with win10 Home. I have set up two family accounts for each of my children. Problem is, that all games and other apps that I have installed on my users also is available for the kids. Is there a way to prevent this? They should have their separate games in their separate users. Games in being installed on D:

Answer (score 0):

If those accounts are marked as a 'child' account you can use 'family settings' in windows 10. This functionality is included in the system already. You can easily block access to unwanted applications/games, you can control screen time, content and more.
You can easily find lots of tutorials on YT and other media on how to configure it.
GL.